# Is there a way to turn Wi-Fi on/off using Spotlight?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, spotlight

Is there a way to turn Wi-Fi on/off using Spotlight, or do I always have to use the mouse and click on the Wi-Fi icon in the taskbar?

Spotlight is pretty powerful, and I would love to have an easy way of enabling/disabling the Wi-Fi connection. Is there a built-in way of doing this, or do I need to create a script for this, and then call the script from Spotlight?

Comment: You could create a script and use the `networksetup` command to toggle its state.  See `-getairportpower` and `-setairportpower` in the manpage for    `networksetup`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best method, but there's at least one way to set a keyword to trigger stuff in spotlight, and that is by making an application with Automator.

Personally I use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) for this type of stuff, but it's not overly difficult to do this with Automator.

1. Open `Automator.app`

   - It should by default ask you what type of file to make, but if it doesn't <kbd>⌘ + N</kbd>
2. **Choose a type for your document:** Application
3. **Start writing:** shell
4. Press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> twice
5. It should now look something like this [image]
6. Replace the `cat` text with: `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off`
7. **Save** ( <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd>  )
8. **Name it:** `Wifi OFF.app`
9. **Duplicate** ( <kbd>⌘ + ⇧  +  S</kbd>  )
10. **Rename to:** `Wifi ON`
11. In the `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off` text, replace the `off` with:  `on`
12. **Save** ( <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd>  )

Now if you open spotlight and write `wifi`, you should see something like this:

[image]

---

---

---

If you want to change the icons, here's an article explaining how in detail: http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/04/change-icon-mac/

Short version:

1. Open the desired image in `Preview.app` (png works the best)
2. Select all ( <kbd>⌘ + A</kbd>  )
3. Copy ( <kbd>⌘ + C</kbd>  )
4. Select the `Wifi On.app` in finder
5. Go to file info: ( <kbd>⌘ + i</kbd>  )
6. Click the current icon on the top left
7. Paste ( <kbd>⌘ + V</kbd>  )

   After changing the icons, you might not see them change immediately. You can force spotlight to see the new icons faster by trashing the apps and then undoing it (taking files off the trast).

[image]

**Links to the icons I used:**

- [Wifi OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQUqh.png)
- [Wifi ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uPjF.png)

Comment: This is great - exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @nwinkler Great :)

Comment: Something I forgot to mention. It may be a bit obvious. If you put these app files to dropbox (for example), you can easily use the same keywords on multiple macs.

Comment: Good answer! Maybe you can make it into a single 'WiFi toggle' app by first checking if the WiFi is on/off with getairportpower and switching accordingly.

Comment: Automator has automatically stored the files in iCloud, so they can be accessed on all of my machines - incredibly useful!